# UISearchBar Disappear From UINavigationBar When Use "back swipe" iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have 2 `ViewController` for both implemented:

```
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()

    func viewDidLoad() {
       navigationItem.titleView = searchBar    
    }
```

When I push second view controller and try go back with swipe gesture, all my navigation items disappearing irrevocably.

Maybe someone has an idea how to fix it?

Images:

SearchBar First VC
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVBP9.png

SearchBar Second VC
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTj8w.png

NavigationBar When starting back swipe
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3kiM.png

Comment: Hey. I have the same issue. How did u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

A navigation item is associated with the view controller. So if you want search bar in both view controllers you have to set the search bar for both the view controllers.

Also, you can use searchController property to show the search bar in the navigation controller. So that you can show the title and search bar in the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case both ViewControllers implemented the same code in viewDidLoad,

Answer (score 0):

A navigation item is associated with the view controller. So if you want to show search bar in both view controllers you have to add it separately in the viewDidLoad method.

And also you can use searchController property to show the search bar in the navigation bar. So that you can show both title and search bar in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this problem by handling UINavigationBarDelegate methods.

1. Use your own UINavigationController because UINavigationController is the default delegate of UINavigationBar, i don't need to reassign delegate to other class to handle.
2. implement these code and get the searchField inside of UISearchBar to minor change its frame.

```
extension YourNavigationController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
  func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: 
 UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
      if let inSearchBar = item.titleView as? UISearchBar,
        let searchField = inSearchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UIView {
          searchField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: searchField.frame.width + 1, height: 36)
      }
  }
}
```

Why i do this is because i found that if the frame of searchField don't change, then the search bar would disappear. It is not a good way to do but a kind of workaround to show the correct view. In iOS 13, i believe we can check to use `searchTextField` to replace `searchField`, a property provided by Apple doc.